# Can I republish what is already published on ArXiv after a copyright transfer?

Tags: publications, copyright, arxiv, license

I will explain the case (because it is unique):

If I publish an article in arXiv under the arXiv license (not under CC license), consequently I retain the copyright.

Four months later, I write other article (a different one), but I use/include parts from the first article. And this second article is not published in arXiv, it is published in a journal (transferring the copyright to the publisher and exclusive publication rights, which is possible since the author is the copyright holder).

Now, if we go back to the first article (which is in arXiv before the second article was published), and we need to modify (for whatever reason) the comments in arXiv... for this it will be necessary to create a second version (v2) and publish again the fulltext file and accept the ArXiv license (certifying that you have the right to grant that license).

If the first article had never been published in arXiv (it would have simply remained on the author's PC), the author would not be able to publish the first article in arXiv, since he would be publishing the first article including content (since the second article was partially a derivative work from the first one) whose copyright was transferred (and the journal allows the publication in arXiv of the second article that is published in the journal, which has nothing to do with the first article).

But, taking into account that the first article was published in arXiv (and is already in arXiv)... can the author republish it (and accept the arXiv license again) or would he be doing something illegal due to the transfer of copyright relative to the second article that included content from the first one?

Comment: Does the journal's copyright transfer agreement mention anything about allowing posting on arXiv / personal webpage? Some allow this as an exception.

Comment: The journal allows the publication of the article in non-commercial repositories, including arXiv. But this applies to the second article.

My question is whether it would be possible to re-grant the arXiv license to the first article after having included part of its content in the second article (whose copyright was transferred).

Comment: If it was the first time that the first article was to be published in arXiv, I think it would not be possible. But, since the first article was already in arXiv before the second article was published...There is my doubt ...

Comment: Can someone give some help with this matter? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Teresa, please don't use answers to bump your question: non-answers are deleted on Stack Exchange (in this case, I converted it to a comment). If you want to draw attention to a question, follow the advice given in [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/300001).